# Using an entire Python Module in Java using Jython?

Tags: java, python, jython

I'm trying to access the `nflgame` python library from java and so I installed `nflgame` using `pip` into `C:\Python23\Lib\site-packages`

I am able to use the nflgame library through IDLE, but after reading the Jython documentation, I don't see how I can execute the entire module using Jython instead of singular .py files.

How would I execute an entire Python Module in Java using Jython? I understand it is more complicated than just interpreting the files, but I can't seem to find out how to load the entire module into `JythonInterpreter`in the first place. The `JythonInterpreter` class only has `.exec()` and `.execFile`

Comment: You may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Can't you do `exec("import nflgame")` and work from there? Btw, the class with an `exec` method is called `PythonInterpreter`, not `JythonInterpreter`.